# Neo4j cypher query takes an infinite time to execute

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

I have loaded in a local docker instance of neo4j 3.3.1 community 147 nodes connected by 1718 relationships. This form a highly cyclic graph.

All the nodes have the same label :EClass and two attributes, class and package.

The following query counts the numbers of classes reachable from the package modelQueryLanguage by following an infinite number of steps.

```
MATCH (a:EClass {package: 'modelQueryLanguage'})-[*1..]->(b)
RETURN count(DISTINCT b)
```

The problem is, this query never finish.

My instinct tells me that the distinct clause is supposed to define a stop condition for the potentially infinite traversal of the graph.

How can I write an equivalent cypher query but which execute fast?

Comment: Run the query with the `EXPLAIN` prefix to get an estimation. For performance optimization, adding relationship types could speed things up, e.g. `-[:EREFERENCE*]->` or whatever type you have. (Note: `1..` is the default for variable length queries, so it can be omitted.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cypher's mode of expansion will attempt to find all possible paths matching the pattern, with the only restriction that a relationship cannot occur more than once per path. With highly connected graphs (and inadequate restrictions on relationship type/direction), this becomes an infeasible means of expansion, as the number of possible unique paths in the graph to every other node in the graph can become huge. This is not ideal for a reachability query.

[APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) has some [path expander procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_expand_paths) that are made specifically for use cases like this, where only a single path per node is needed, not all possible paths. And if you just need the nodes and not the paths, there's a procedure for that too.

Here's an example of usage for your query:

```
MATCH (a:EClass {package: 'modelQueryLanguage'})
CALL apoc.path.subgraphNodes(a, {relationshipFilter:'>'}) YIELD node
RETURN count(node) as count
```